# Nestjs throws 500 Internal Server error instead of the intended error

Tags: node.js, nestjs, nest

So I'm trying to throw my 403 Forbidden error via the HttpException module imported from nest @nestjs/common from a microservice to a gateway, but nest keeps throwing it as a 500 Internal Server error.

The JSON.stringify of the generated error is:

```
{"response":"User already exists","status":403,"message":"User already exists","name":"HttpException"}
```

The error displayed in the gateway is:

```
[Nest] 4747  - 11/06/2022, 18:01:58   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] Internal server error
[Nest] 4747  - 11/06/2022, 18:01:58   ERROR [ExceptionsHandler] undefined
```

Any idea whats up with that?

Here's the service that throws an error:

```
import { Model } from 'mongoose';
import {
  Injectable,
  Inject,
  ForbiddenException,
  HttpException,
  HttpStatus,
} from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectModel } from '@nestjs/mongoose';

import { User, UserDocument } from './schemas/user.schema';

@Injectable()
export class AccountManagementService {
  constructor(@InjectModel(User.name) private userModel: Model<UserDocument>) {}
  async createUser(user: any): Promise<any> {
    const existingUser = await this.userModel.find({
      $or: [{ username: user.username }, { email: user.email }],
    });
    if (existingUser) {
      throw new HttpException('User already exists', HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN);
    }
    const createdUser = new this.userModel(user);
    return createdUser.save();
  }
}
```

And here's the controller:

```
import { Controller, Post } from '@nestjs/common';
import { MessagePattern } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AccountManagementService } from './account-management.service';

@Controller()
export class AccountManagementController {
  constructor(
    private accountManagementService: AccountManagementService,
  ) {}

  @MessagePattern({ cmd: 'createUser' })
  async createUser(userData: any): Promise<any> {
    return this.accountManagementService
      .createUser(userData)
  }
}
```

Comment: May you provide the thrown exception that causes the 500-response, so we can be sure that the `HttpException` is really thrown and it is not some other exception arising within your code?

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code to see whether it enters if statement or not? As my understandings, there is nothing wrong with your exception handling and this should work.

Comment: I also have this same issue. I want to throw a 404 error, but nest js keeps throwing the 500 error

Comment: I am getting the same issue, I am using a hybrid app with two transport for one microservice that is TCP and RMQP, any idea what the issue is?

Comment: same error here, my case is a little bit different but i believe is the same underlying problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78121110/nest-js-on-cloud-function-not-sending-out-http-error-message

Answer (score -2):

So what i basically did was handle the errors thrown from the service in the controllers try and catch block, so any error caught from the service gets thrown with the right status code and description
user.controller.ts

```
import { Controller, Post, Body, HttpCode, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';
import { AuthDto, SigninDto } from './dto';

@Controller('auth')
export class AuthController {
  constructor(private readonly authService: AuthService) {}

  @HttpCode(HttpStatus.OK)
  @Post('signin')
  async signin(@Body() dto: SigninDto) {
    try {
      return this.authService.signin(dto);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }

  @Post('signup')
  async signup(@Body() dto: AuthDto) {
    try {
      return this.authService.signup(dto);
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

Then this is my signup function in the user service

```
async signup(dto: AuthDto): Promise<any> {
const account = await this.userModel.findOne({
  phoneNumber: dto.phoneNumber,
});
if (account) {
  throw new ForbiddenException(
    'An account with this phoneNumber already exists',
  );
}
const SALT = 10;
const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(dto.password, SALT);
const newUser = await this.userService.create({
  name: dto.name,
  password: hashedPassword,
  phoneNumber: dto.phoneNumber,
});
return newUser;
```

}

Comment: Catching and rethrowing has absolutely no difference than not catching it in the first palce.